# Prevent URLS in UIWebView from opening Yelp (or other) Apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, yelp

I am loading a yelp URL into a UIWebView and want to display the mobile website instead of automatically opening Yelp App.  Behavior is as expected in my simulator, but goes to yelp on my phone since I have the yelp app installed.

Below is my code to load the URL:

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http://yelp.com/search?find_desc=coffee&find_loc=union+square";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_yelpView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this? I am dealing with the same problem for another app.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't, just ended up modifying my functionality so that it was ok that it opened into the yelp app :S

Answer (score 0):

It can be because the yelp web page could ask about the redirect with some custom URL scheme which then is recognized by Yelp app.

You should debug which requests your web view performs during the loading of Yelp web page.

try to set a delegate to your web view and check which requests it performs with this delegate callback:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Comment: Once you know the request, what do you have to do to prevent the app from opening?